# How do you display a variable with Tinybox

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage where I would like to have a button that opens a [Tinybox](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/) window but would like the contents diplayed to be a variable, that way I could have mulitple button, each displaying a different string.

Static text works fine but a variable just stops the thing dead, below is the sort of thing I'm trying...

```
TINY.box.show({html:'$summary',width:300,height:150})
```

I've tried different option but cant get it to work, ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on what exactly you are trying to do, but if it is to have the html property on the tinybox options be the contents of the variable `$summary`, you can simply assign it like so:

```
// assuming $summary is a string
// e.g. var $summary = 'index.html';
TINY.box.show({html: $summary,width:300,height:150})
```

Unlike some languages (namely PHP) javascript does not print variables within strings.